# Passagem de ponteiro de ponteiro por referência

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Estou fazendo um programa onde preciso alocar dinamicamente 2 matrizes, então pensei em fazer essa alocação dentro de uma função. Tentei fazer desta forma, mas está dando "Falha de segmentação". Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
void CriaMatriz(int ***matriz, int linhas, int colunas){

    int i,j;

    /* Alocação das linhas da matriz. */
    matriz = (int ***) malloc(linhas * sizeof(int **));

    /* Alocação das colunas da matriz. */
    for (i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {

        matriz[i] = (int **) malloc(colunas * sizeof(int*));

        /* Preenchimento da matriz. */
        for (j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
            scanf("%d", matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int **matriz1, linhas, colunas;

    CriaMatriz(&matriz1, linhas, colunas);

}
```

Comment: Tem alguns erros conceituais aí no seu código. O primeiro é que você alocou até no máximo o nível de ponteiro de ponteiro de inteiro, o que significa que você poderia manipular ponteiros de inteiro, mas não o inteiro em si. O outro erro que eu vi é que você está alocando um ponteiro de ponteiro de ponteiro, e atribuindo o resultado dessa alocação em `matriz`, quando você gostaria que a função que chamou `CriaMatriz` tivesse o primeiro parâmetro com o valor da alocação, então você deveria alocar ponteiro de ponteiro e guardar o resultado do `malloc` em `(*matriz)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns erros no código referentes ao entendimento do que está acontecendo. Uma matriz bidimensional pode ser representada como um ponteiro para ponteiro, no seu caso, como citado nos comentários, você estava tentando fazer uma espécie de array tridimensional. A imagem abaixo é uma representação de como isso fica na memória.

[image: Arrays como ponteiros]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** CriaMatriz(int linhas, int colunas);

int main(int argc, char* argv){
    int **matriz1, i, linhas = 2, colunas = 2;

    matriz1 = CriaMatriz(linhas, colunas);

    // Após uso deve-se liberar a memória
    for (i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
        // Liberando as linhas
        free(matriz1[i]);
    }

    // Liberando o apontador principal
    free(matriz1);
}

int** CriaMatriz(int linhas, int colunas){
    // Você estava manipulando uma variável local
    int i,j, **matriz;

    // Agora temos a alocação correta, teremos X ponteiros para ponteiros
    matriz = (int**) malloc(linhas * sizeof(int*));

    // Cada ponteiro terá X colunas de inteiros
    for (i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        matriz[i] = (int*) malloc(colunas * sizeof(int));
    }

    /* Preenchimento da matriz. */
    for (i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < colunas; j++) {
            // Nós colocamos o valor no endereço apontado
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // retornando o endereço principal
    return matriz;
}
```